# Select r balls of n, s.t. the sequence is increasing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Suppose we have n balls designated by $1,2,...n$ and we select without replacement $r$ balls $(r\le n)$. What is the probability that we selected an increasing sequence of numbers ?

we have $\binom{n}{r}$ ways in selecting $r$ balls of $n$, in this case it depends on the order, Hence $r!\binom{n}{r}$ ways. This would be the denominator

and if we choose r balls, we can always change the order to get an increasing sequence, So we get $\dfrac{\binom{n}{r}}{r!\binom{n}{r}}=\dfrac{1}{r!}$

Comment: I do not think that you are interpreting the question correctly, or the answer would be 1. (you can always form an increasing sequence by rearranging r balls, since ball numbers are unique)

Comment: The question only makes sense, if the balls/numbers are considered in the order they've been picked. **Hint:** This is equivalent to count all strictly monotic increasing length-$r$ sequences in $\{1,2,..,n\}$.

Comment: Say, we've chosen r balls. we can arrange this set of r elements in $r!$ ways, but only one of these is ''increasing'' ?

Comment: The question is not if we *can* rearrange this, but if the task allows to rearrange them. So how do you imagine the experiment? Say you have $n=r=3$ and you pick the balls in the order $[2,3,1]$. In your opinion, is $[2,3,1]$ already your result, or do you perform a reordering?

Comment: @flonk possible selections $\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,2\},\{2,3,1\},\{2,1,3\},\{3,1,2\},\{3,2,1\}$ but one in the right order, result=1/6

Comment: In a way, there is no question here. You stated a problem, and solved it. Correctly of course.

Comment: @O.B.D.A. alright, I was just misunderstanding your explanation. So what's your question?

Comment: @flonk I only needed a confirmation (or a correction) if my approach is correct.

Comment: @O.B.D.A., Your answer is correct!